# eliminating parenthesis in index string entries in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where some indices include unwanted characters, mainly the parenthesis "(". A loop needs to go over every row and eliminate "(" and everything after it.

```
   for index, row in df.iterrows():

       index = index[:index.rfind("(")]

       newindexlist.append(index)

    df.index = newindexlist
```

The problem is that it eliminates an extra character off of every entry. For example when the index is abcd , then it changes it to abc. While if the index is abcd(blah) then it changes the index entry to abcd. How can I prevent it from eliminating extra character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['one(two)', 'five (three)two', '(blah)two', '1 three  blah haha1'], 'B': [100,200,300,400]})
df = df.set_index('A')


                    B
A   
one(two)            100
five (three)two     200
(blah)two           300
three blah haha1    400

df.index = df.index.str.extract('([\s\w]*)\(*')
```

Will give you

```
                    B
A   
one                 1
five                2
                    3
three blah haha 1   4
```

Comment: This is amazing in its simplicity.

Comment: Sorry missed the index part. df.index = df.index.str.extract('(\w*)\(*') works equally well

Comment: To make this answer more useful and general, could you add a brief description on what each of the characters in the command works? ('(\w*)\(*')

Comment: This is regex match. (\w*) would extract every alpha-numeric value till it finds the \( opening parenthesis. The * after opening parenthesis ensures it extracts the value in the event there is no parenthesis in a cell.

Comment: Problem. It eliminates spaces, as if it sees spaces as parentheses. If you change 'three' to 'three blah' , it returns 'three'.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should avoid using loops in pandas. They are bad performance wise and Pandas are much more effective when you manipulate entire dataset instead of iterating rows in for loop.

Assuming you want to remove only the parentheses,

```
import re
def remove_parentheses(x):
    return re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', x['field'])
```

then

```
df['index'] = df.apply(lambda x: remove_parentheses(x), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question to clarify. I wanted to eliminate parentheses and everything after the first parenthesis. So abcd (blah) should become abcd.

Comment: yup, to remove everything after the first instance of a "bad" character you can just split each string on the bad character and take the first element of the result

Answer (score 1):

For the case when index is abcd, it changes to abc because `index.rfind("(")` returns `-1` since `"("` is not found. This results in `index = index[:-1]`

You should check for when `"("` is in the index and when it is not. You can do something like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index.rfind("(") != -1:
        index = index[:index.rfind("(")]

    newindexlist.append(index)

df.index = newindexlist
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something even more simple (though tempting to use regex)

```
import pandas as pd
import re

pattern = r"(.*)\("
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["abcd(blah)", "abcd",])
print df.index

Index([u'abcd(blah)', u'abcd'], dtype='object')

df = df.reset_index()
df['index'] = df['index'].apply(lambda x: x.split("(")[0])
df.set_index("index", inplace=True)
print df.index

Index([u'abcd', u'abcd'], dtype='object', name=u'index')
```